# Open Mapping In the Reals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This problem is throwing me for a loop. Any help would be appreciated.

If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + cx + 3$, f is an open map for which values of $c$?

Comment: Do you know any conditions for when a continuous function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is an open map?  Do you know whether $x^2$ or $x^3$ are open?

Comment: Sure. $x^2$ is not an open map, because it maps $(-1,1)$ to $\[0,1)$. $x^3$ is an open map. Thank you for the prodding, I'm looking for a nudge or two in the correct direction in order to understand it on my own.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Thank you for your question.  We will be able to better answer it if you give the context of the problem, any nonstandard or unusual definitions, and share what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that function had a local maximum or minimum at $x_0$, then the image of $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$ for $\delta$ small enough wouldn't be open (sketch a graph). So we must ask $f$ to be a monotonic (increasing in this case) function.

Since the derivative is $f'=3x^2+6x+c=3(x+1)^2+(c-3)$, $c$ must be bigger or equal to 3 in order for that not to be negative.